# NReal adb and scrcpy not working after update

Tags: nreal

I am using NReal developer glasses, devkit. Within NReal user interface (using the glasses) it said an update to the OS was available, so I clicked to update using the NReal controller and glasses.

The operating system updated and NReal still works with the glasses, but I cannot connect with scrcpy and adb, adb devices doesn't show any connected devices.

I guess that perhaps the debug mode on the NReal light developer device is now not enabled. So how to enable the debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem was that I was not using the USB type C, I was using the other more common USB type. USB type C needs to plug from the PC to the device into where the glasses plug in. Problem solved.